# Alert opens every time and not only the first time

Tags: ios, swift

I want my alert to only open the first time the app is launched on a new device but it currently opens every time the app is closed in multitasking and opened again. I have attached my code if anyone is able to help please?

```
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        // alert first time app is opened
        // making of alert

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Navigation", message: "Tap Right Hand Side of Screen For Next Quote, Left Hand Side To Go Back", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

        //add ok button
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))

        // detect if first launch
        let launchedBefore = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "launcedBefore")
        if launchedBefore {
        }
        else {
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "launchedBefore")
        }
    }
```

Comment: viewDidAppear is not the right place.

Comment: @ElTomato it is definitely the right place.

Comment: That should teach you to use constants for strings. `"launchedBefore"` vs `"launcedBefore"`.

Comment: @ElTomato In `viewDidLoad` the view hierarchy is not fully set but in `viewDidAppear` it is set, so it is definitely the right place to present `UIAlertController`.

Comment: just one more addition. Use appdidifinishluanching of App delegate for this task.

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your keys... While writing it you are using key `launchedBefore`  but when read it you are using `launcedBefore`

Answer (score 0):

This is the reason why I hate using UserDefaults. Sometimes you make typos and you can't tell where it's happening.

The best way to use UserDefaults is to create all the keys into constants, so your two lines accessing UserDefaults would look something cleaner like this:

```
let launchedBefore = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: kLaunchedBeforeKey)
```

and

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: kLaunchedBeforeKey)
```

This way the compiler will let you know in case you make a typo.

Comment: Well, the best way to use `UserDefaults` is to wrap them into a custom class, e.g. `MySettings`, which has properties and not text keys. The usage of the text keys should be kept in one file.

Comment: Yes, I agree! I started doing that recently.